# click on multiple links and save as pdf

Tags: excel, vba, matlab

I have 40 links imported in an excel sheet. Each link, when clicked, will lead to (Print as file) window for the page.

Is there anyway to open the multiple links and save the page as PDF with specific format (Year_Month_date) with one click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create PDF-File with Timestamp**

this should work for you! you can delete "hhmmss" for only Year_Month_Day !

```
Sub PDFCreate()
Sheets("Tabelle1").PageSetup.Orientation = 1 ' 1=portrait, 2=landscape
With Sheets("Tabelle1")
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$I$21"
    .ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "C:\Users\username\Documents\foldername\" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd hhmmss") & "pdfname.pdf", , , False
End With
End Sub
```

**Print and Open Webpage from VBA Code**

```
Sub print_PDF()

    Dim Explorer As Object
    Dim eQuery As Long ' return value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fTime As Single
    
    Set Explorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") ' Connect to Explorer
    Dim url As String
    url = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
    Explorer.Navigate url ' Open document from local or web!

TryAgain:

        'Wait 2 seconds to let IE load

        fTime = Timer

        Do While fTime > Timer - 2

            DoEvents

        Loop

        eQuery = Explorer.QueryStatusWB(6)  ' print command

        If eQuery And 2 Then

            Explorer.ExecWB 6, 2, "", ""   ' Print (6), displaying dialog (2)

            'Wait for 2 seconds while IE prints

            fTime = Timer

            Do While fTime > Timer - 2

                DoEvents

            Loop

        Else

            GoTo TryAgain

        End If

 

End Sub
```

**UPDATE: Added Insert Option**

u are able to insert link into input dialog, it automatically changes link in `Sub pdf_Print()`

```
Sub Insert()
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = InputBox("Need Input")
Range("A1").Value = myValue
End Sub
```

Comment: will each link be read from each cell and each corresponding page will be printed as pdf ?

Comment: @Jamal not sure what u mean? maybe you should post a screenshot of your worksheet. u can define your printing area  .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$I$21"  . Change the cells to your printing area.

Comment: Let us say these are the pages we want to save

https://www.windfinder.com/weatherforecast/spadeadam_raf

https://www.windfinder.com/weatherforecast/carlisle

what is requested is once we run the code, the page is automatically saved as a pdf or jpeg

Comment: @Jamal so u want to print a website??

Comment: @Jamal Do u paste website links into your worksheet and you want to save them as a pdf by clicking vba? please explain

Comment: exactly ... print as PDF then save it in specific directory or save as jpeg

Comment: okay now i understand your problem!! @Jamal let me try and i will tell u in a few

Comment: okay Thanks alot

Comment: @Jamal i added a new function! U need MS Edge and can insert a webpage in     `Explorer.Navigate "www.google.com"` then i prints. My next step is to insert a button to print several webpages for you as you described

Comment: @Jamal pls try wether this is working so far :) i will add the new function later

Comment: Thanks alot! the website opens, but no pages or screenshots are saved as pdf/jpeg .. I guess we have to add this

Comment: The code works perfectly! Is there a way to save the file automatically in a specific directory with a specific naming ? Year_Month_day

Comment: @Jamal i added the `Sub Insert()` ! Now u will do two buttons. One With `Sub Insert()` macro and the other one with `Sub print_PDF()` macro. First u press `Sub Insert()` and paste your link in it, it will save the input in A1 and in the VBA print_PDF. You can now easily change the page you want to print!! Very nice, isn´t it :) Right now, i am working on the PDF save option!! You can verify my answer as solution, would be very motivating :) please try wether you like the new insert feature

Comment: @Jamal did u already tested the new version, with both buttons?

Comment: Sub Insert(www.google.com) ist that what you mean ? It didn't work :(

Comment: but I'm fine with the 1st code, it worked perfectly! I guess it is enough for me to run my work so far. Thanks a lot and will verify your answer

Comment: @Jamal thanks, so the SubInsert code you insert into vba, then u make a second button and assign the marco on the button. Now u can insert your links into the button and it will change in print_PDF the link to print

Comment: thanks a lot. working perfectly. Could you please check my other question posted today ? thanks